# Redirect from servlet back to the jsp with empty text fields

Tags: jsp, servlets

The case I'm facing is that I have a JSP form connected to a servlet and a submit button, I also have a validation procedure in the servlet page, When some validations are violated I wan to go back to the jsp that has the form but when I do all the text field are empty.
How can I do it ?
I mean how can I go back to the jsp page and the text fields are full with the same values they where before submitting ?

```
  messages.put("Applied", "Sorry, but you already Applied");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/Nurses.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Please can anyone help me as fast as possible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript history back, just print this in case of invalid data and page will return on client side back.

```
<script>
     window.history.go(-1);
</script>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you, but is there any drawbacks of using that way ?

Comment: sure, drawback is - if your form is not static and generating by javascript on some user's event (like `click here to open form`), than form will be empty, but in general, there is no more drawbacks, you just return user back to previous page from his history, if you have some javascript handlers on that page - in most cases thay will work correct, except onLoad event, but javascript has a way to work around this (http://google.com/search?q=onLoad+javascript+history+back)

Comment: Ok thank you so much, but about the java script, isn't there anyway to get back the java script action that had been taken !
In my form the user can add a column on a table but when he goes back he wont find it, how can I solve that out ?

Comment: It is possible, but you have bad design here. It might be better for you send the form with javascript in iframe, OR use AJAX for submitting the form. And if evrything goes OK, in AJAX callback you need to navigate to reqired page with results. But if you want still use current aproach, before submitting form you need to store user data somewhere(`localStorege` is best place) and then in returning read data from storege and applying changes on table back. BUT switching to AJAX will be much better for you. In case of AJAX you will have full control on application flow (including form submiting)

Answer (score 0):

You are sending same request object to your jsp page. Fill all the fields again by using this request object.

Another option is using `ajax` to do your server-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common use case in servlet + JSP. And it is the reason why there are attributes in requests.

You should in your servlet store interesting values in request attributes before *forwarding* (*redirecting* is different and must not be used here) to the JSP.

In the JSP, you just try to get the values from the request attributes. If they are present, use them (when forwarded from a validation error), if not (normal case) you will get null values that will be displayed as empty in the JSP.

(you can use `<jsp:usebean>` to get the request attributes)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using same request  & response object , So you ll be in same session.

1) Store value of all form parameters(JSP FORM) to HttpSession object in Servlet.

HttpSession session = request.getSession();

and using session.setAttribute() method , save all form element value

2) Retrieve all field value back in JSP using HttpSession Object in JSP

```
Retrieve  form element value using session.getAttribute()
```

Thanks 
SP

Comment: OK this is useful, but in that case I have to set and get the values one by one, and I have a lot of fields and most of them can be added, i.e for some fields the user can add up to 7 fields !!
How can I deal with them !!

Comment: If feeling lot of burden then add only field of your intrest and for next request user will again add remaining fields

Answer (score 0):

Since your forwarding request from servlet to jsp, try using EL & taglibs in jsp, e.g.:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!-- ${param.name} will give the value which was submitted -->
<form>
  User name: <input type="text" name="user" value="${param.user}"/>
  <br/>
  Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value='m'
    <c:if test="${'m' eq param.gender}"> checked='checked' </c:if>
     /> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value='f'
    <c:if test="${'f' eq param.gender}"> checked='checked' </c:if>
     /> Female
</form>
```